# VSCode devcontainer connect to kubernetes cluster on vm

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

### Ultimate Goal

From a dotnet/core/sdk devcontainer (using VSCode Remote Containers), debug a .NET Core app running in a kubernetes cluster hosted on another vm of my host machine.

### Current Setup

- Docker Desktop for Windows running via Hyper-V

  - default DockerNAT network adapter
- Ubuntu VM (multipass) running on same Hyper-V host

  - microk8s cluster running on this ubuntu instance
  - default "Default Switch" network adapter

### Errors

- When I try to ping the ubuntu vm from a docker container by hostname, the IP is resolved properly but I get the error "Destination Host Unreachable"
- When I try to curl the cluster api, I get the error "No route to host"

Comment: so you have a machine, that runs Windows (in virtual env) and virtual Ubuntu , which in turn runs micro k8s. Am I right at that point?Are you able to ping for example 8.8.8.8 from a docker container  ? Are you able to reach Cluster aoi from Ubuntu?

Comment: My host machine is Windows 10 Pro, running Docker for Desktop (linux containers) and a virtual Ubuntu. Bock docker and ubuntu run through Hyper-V. The microk8s cluster is running on the virtual Ubuntu. 

From the docker container, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and google.com no problem.

From the ubuntu vm, I can reach the cluster api.

From the docker container, I can resolve the ubuntu hostname (microk8s.mshome.net), but I get "Destination Host Unreachable".

Comment: It looks like the issue with networking between Docker and Ubuntu. Have you tried to create a single NAT and attach VMs to it as it is described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network ?

Comment: I had put both VMs on Docker's default DockerNAT network, but that didn't work. I would try your suggestion, but for unknown reasons the issue is no longer reproducible as I will explain in my "solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this problem aside for a week, and over that time the host has been rebooted multiple times, but no further modifications were made to the networking, Hyper-V setup, etc.

Starting the Ubuntu VM today, the IP changed from what used to be 172.?.?.? to 192.168.92.x . I do not know what caused this change.

Now, Docker Desktop containers **can** ping the Ubuntu VM and curl the microk8s /api endpoint. Until such a time that I can reproduce the issue, I will mark this question as "solved" and reopen and try Nick's recommended solution if the issue returns.